# Error getting more than two eigenvalues in PCA

Tags: python, machine-learning, seaborn, pca

I am trying to perform PCA from scratch on a subset of MNIST data(digits 0 and 1) using Python.
(**NOTE**: x_train_0_scaled has dimensions : 5923x784 where 5923 is the number of images and 784 is the 28*28 flattened pixel values)

Here's my code to find eigenvalues:

```
# matrix multiplication using numpy
covar_matrix = np.matmul(x_train_0_scaled.T, x_train_0_scaled)

print("The shape of variance matrix = ", covar_matrix.shape)

# the parameter 'eigvals' is defined (low value to heigh value)
# eigh function will return the eigen values in asending order
# this code generates only the top 2 (782 and 783)(index) eigenvalues.
values, vectors = eigh(covar_matrix, eigvals=(782, 783))

print("Shape of eigen vectors = ", vectors.shape)
```

However when I try to get more than two eigenvalues, I get this error:

```
    values, vectors = eigh(covar_matrix, eigvals=(782, 783, 781))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp.py", line 484, in eigh
    lo, hi = [int(x) for x in subset_by_index]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The reason I want more than two eigenvectors is because as per the image below, I guess my data is not clearly seperable so I want to find more dimensions to plot my data on. Is my intuition correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. eigvals takes arguments as (lo, hi). So instead of specifying (781,782, 783) I needed to specify lo=781 and hi=783 to get the top 3 eigenvalues.